# Do level 2 quotes help a non day trader?

Tags: real-time-quotes, level-2-quotes

My broker is trying to sell me expensive data packages that show level 2 quotes. If I am not a day trader and my minimum holding period is 3-4 days, do I get any advantage by purchasing level 2 quotes?

I thought level 2 quotes were only for HFT firms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are trading illiquid securities or very large quantities, level 2 quotes are not useful. Particularly if you will be using limit orders.